# Calculating the area of a simple polygon

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

given a polygon P, i want to calculate the area of the polygon.

my solution:
find a triangulation, and sum all the area of the triangles.

Total time complexity: o(nlogn).

Does there exist a better solution?

Comment: In which format is provided the polygon? If the edges are ordered, a triangulation can be performed in O(n), at least for a convex polygon.

Comment: @Damien: any simple polygon can be triangulated in worst-case time O(n). But the algorithm is so difficult that one can doubt it was ever programmed. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly decompose, use the shoelace formula. It is easy and O(n).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

---

The method generalizes to the computation of *geometric moments*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Any_polygon